# Can I choose to resolve a promise only in a part of if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

Hello,

I have functions in a module that are designed like this :

```js
myFunction: function(some args, myBoolean) {
  var deffered = q.defer()
  if(myBool) {
    module.exports.mySecondfunction(args, false, null)
  } else {
    return module.exports.mySecondfunction(args, true, deffered)
},

mySecondFunction: function(some args, myBoolean, myPromise) {
  //Some work here
  if(myBoolean) {
    //Some work
    promise.resolve();
    return myPromise.promise
  }
}

anotherFunction: function(some args) {
  //some work
  if (something) {
    myFunction(some args, true)
  } else {
    myFunction(some args, false).then((data) => {
      //do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

When anotherFunction is triggered and goes to "else" part, my server throws an error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Line where it fails is :

> myFunction(some args, false).then((data) => {...

Do you have any idea about what is wrong with my code ? Is there anyway to promised a function only if a boolean is set to True ?

Comment: You should almost never pass deferreds around. Make `mySecondFunction` construct its own promise if it wants to return one.

Comment: Yes, it's a very bad idea to sometimes return a promise and sometimes not. Just return an already-fulfilled promise if you are in a branch that doesn't do anything asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a promise on both functions. May use something like:

```
anotherFunction: function(some args, myBoolean, myPromise) {
  //some work
  if (something) {
    myFunction(some args, true)
  } else {
    myFunction(some args, false).then((data) => {
      //do stuff
    }
  }
  myPromise.resolve();
  return myPromise.promise;
}
```

Promises in this case serve to abstract async/sync methods variations, which will make it easier for you if you ever need to change `anotherFunction` into a true async.

BTW: I don't think you should be exporting promises, you could make your code more reusable if you exported a function that when called returned a promise, like exporting `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to resolve your promises.

I'm just going to go ahead and recommend using `async/await` syntax.  Currently you need `babel` for this.

```
async function takesAwhile(otherFirst) {
  if (otherFirst) await doOtherThing();
  return doStuff();    
}
```

Comment: I believe the `await` in the `return` statement is redundant.

Comment: I was just thinking hypothetically this doStuff was also async.  Could be either.

Comment: It does not matter, if it is async or not. `return await` is not distinguishable from `return`. PS: I really like the "about" in your profile! :-D

Comment: Wasn't aware so I will have to test that but it didn't need to say await anyway for the example so I changed it.

Comment: Do i have to use `babel` ? Is `Q`not enough ?

Comment: The goal is to make the code easier for you to understand. But you will benefit also from learning promises well.  Try using a debugger or console.logs to step through your code carefully.